# Is there any way to extend Data.Vector to accept 2D indices, without having to almost rewrite the whole library?

Tags: haskell, inheritance, vector, typeclass

My program needs a Matrix type that works exactly the same as the Vector types on Hackage, except using 2D points instead of Ints for indexing. I've started creating such extension, which shows below:

```
module Data.Matrix.Mutable where

import Control.Monad.Primitive
import Control.Monad.ST
import Linear
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed.Mutable as MUV
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as UV

data MMatrix s t = MMatrix { dim :: V2 Int, buffer :: MUV.MVector s t }

indexToPos :: Int -> Int -> V2 Int
indexToPos width index = V2 (quot index width) (mod index width)

posToIndex :: Int -> V2 Int -> Int
posToIndex width (V2 x y) = y * width + x

width :: MMatrix s t -> Int
width  (MMatrix (V2 w _) _) = w

height :: MMatrix s t -> Int
height (MMatrix (V2 _ h) _) = h

new :: (PrimMonad m, MUV.Unbox t) => V2 Int -> m (MMatrix (PrimState m) t)
new (dim@(V2 w h)) = return . MMatrix dim =<< MUV.new (w * h)

write :: (PrimMonad m, MUV.Unbox t) => MMatrix (PrimState m) t -> V2 Int -> t -> m ()
write matrix pos val = MUV.write (buffer matrix) (posToIndex (width matrix) pos) val

read :: (PrimMonad m, MUV.Unbox t) => MMatrix (PrimState m) t -> V2 Int -> m t
read matrix pos = MUV.read (buffer matrix) (posToIndex (width matrix) pos)
```

On the progress, I've noticed I'm forced to manually write a wrapper for every single function for every single vector type. That process is not only tedious, but has high maintenance costs, since any change on their API will need an equally big change on my code. In a dynamic language, the solution is much simpler: overwrite the "read" and "write" functions on a Vector base type. Example (in JavaScript):

```
Matrix = clone(Vector);
Matrix.read = function(x,y){
    return Vector.read.call(this, this.width * y + x);
};
Matrix.set = function(x,y,val){
    return Vector.write.call(this, this.width * y + x, val);
};
```

From now on, Matrix works exactly like Vector, except indexed by 2D points, as intended. What is the equivalent strategy on Haskell (using typeclasses, I guess)?

Comment: Use hmatrix (http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hmatrix)

Comment: Is there any tutorial/guide? Every link there seems broken. Also, someone at Haskell pointed out a few good solutions (such as using Data.Array). Yet, I'm interested in an actual answer to the question as asked for the sake of knowledge. Thank you very much!

Comment: Code examples: http://dis.um.es/~alberto/hmatrix/hmatrix.html

Comment: Consider yarr or repa, which are designed for multidimensional.

Comment: Repa is quite similar to Vector, and supports arbitrary (typed) dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

> My program needs a Matrix type that works exactly the same as the Vector types on Hackage, except using 2D points instead of Ints for indexing

The answer is to use a library for 2 (or higher) dimensional matrices.

You can choose between those close to vector

- [repa](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/repa)
- [matrix](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/matrix)

or further away

- [hmatrix](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hmatrix)

Repa is built on top of vector.

Comment: I appreciate that answer since it solves the practical issue posted, but it doesn't solve the actual inner problem, which is extending builtin types with different interfaces. What if I, for example, wanted a matrix that worked with polar coordinates?

Comment: You get to program against the API the library has exposed. Normally for vector-alikes, you would overload the indexing type. This works for e.g. the base array library that is parameterized by coordinates. For vector, you have to write a wrapper that does it, since it is specialized to word-sized indexing.